# Can I rename my Gemfile to Gemfile.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Without a file extension I can't get syntax highlighting to persist. That's not the end of the world, but I'd appreciate having it.

Will it break Rails if I rename `Gemfile` as `Gemfile.rb` ?

Comment: Using Coda. I can change syntax mode to RB, but it won't remember that setting for an individual file, it only lets you associate particular extensions with a syntax mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you can rename it, but bundler will not automatically find it.

However, you can just prepend every bundler command with `BUNDLE_GEMFILE=Gemfile.rb` and it'll work:

```
BUNDLE_GEMFILE=Gemfile.rb bundle install
```

You might also look at http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-config.1.html -- It mentions a gemfile option, but I couldn't get it to work (even after manually setting it to `Gemfile.rb`, it still tried to look for `Gemfile`).